i get an error with magicblast.exe from NCBI in windows without further information what could be wrong
i tried to use the ncbi blast downloadable database from their ftp https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/ with the magicblast.exe for winx64, extracted the tar.gz archive like stated in the readme to a folder called virus and used the following command to query my FAST genetic data for viruses in windows x64 from the command line with administrator rights:
magicblast.exe -db D:\BLAST\bin\virus\ref_viruses_rep_genomes -query F:\Genetics\XXXXX_1.fq.gz -outfmt tabular -out result.csv
but i got this error:

Warning: (210.70) [magicblast] [CZipDecompressor::Process]  buffer error;  error code = -5, number of processed bytes = 1554

BLAST query/options error: FASTA parse error: defline expected


for the second error i found a solution, i use a fastq file and not a fasta file, therefore i had to add -infmt fastq, then this error was gone, but the first error still exists.
i don't know what could be wrong here..
it looks like an Unarchive error from the magicblast.exe, but i googled for this error and didn't find any information related to these errors.
